# Python sort function not sorting properly?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dict with 5 values:

```
dict2 = {
'Buffalo Bills': [{'plyoffStats': [1, 6, 140.0, 170.0, {'winPct': 0.143}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [1, 5]}, {'div': [0, 1]}, {'conf': [0, 0]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}],
'Miami Dolphins': [{'plyoffStats': [3, 8, 126.0, 309.0, {'winPct': 0.273}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [3, 5]}, {'div': [0, 3]}, {'conf': [0, 0]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}],
'Seattle Seahawks': [{'plyoffStats': [14, 13, 659.0, 593.0, {'winPct': 0.519}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [7, 4]}, {'div': [3, 7]}, {'conf': [3, 0]}, {'sb': [1, 2]}]}],
'Houston Texans': [{'plyoffStats': [4, 6, 194.0, 253.0, {'winPct': 0.4}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [4, 2]}, {'div': [0, 4]}, {'conf': [0, 0]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}],
'Pittsburgh Steelers': [{'plyoffStats': [19, 13, 790.0, 730.0, {'winPct': 0.594}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [5, 3]}, {'div': [8, 4]}, {'conf': [4, 4]}, {'sb': [2, 2]}]}],
'Jacksonville Jaguars': [{'plyoffStats': [7, 7, 337.0, 357.0, {'winPct': 0.5}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [4, 2]}, {'div': [3, 2]}, {'conf': [0, 3]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}],
}
```

I am trying to sort those values by `plyoffStats[0]`using:

```
sortedByWinPct2 = {k:v for k, v in sorted(dict2.items(), key= lambda v:v[0][0], reverse=True)}
```

But I get the following result which is not sorted:

```
[{'plyoffStats': [14, 13, 659.0, 593.0, {'winPct': 0.519}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [7, 4]}, {'div': [3, 7]}, {'conf': [3, 0]}, {'sb': [1, 2]}]}]
[{'plyoffStats': [19, 13, 790.0, 730.0, {'winPct': 0.594}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [5, 3]}, {'div': [8, 4]}, {'conf': [4, 4]}, {'sb': [2, 2]}]}]
[{'plyoffStats': [3, 8, 126.0, 309.0, {'winPct': 0.273}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [3, 5]}, {'div': [0, 3]}, {'conf': [0, 0]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}]
[{'plyoffStats': [7, 7, 337.0, 357.0, {'winPct': 0.5}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [4, 2]}, {'div': [3, 2]}, {'conf': [0, 3]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}]
[{'plyoffStats': [4, 6, 194.0, 253.0, {'winPct': 0.4}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [4, 2]}, {'div': [0, 4]}, {'conf': [0, 0]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}]
[{'plyoffStats': [1, 6, 140.0, 170.0, {'winPct': 0.143}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [1, 5]}, {'div': [0, 1]}, {'conf': [0, 0]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}]
```

I also tried directly choosing the number like so -

```
sortedByWinPct2 = {k:v for k, v in sorted(dict2.items(), key= lambda v:v[0]['plyfOffStats'], reverse=True)}
```

But i get the **TypeError: string indices must be integers**

Not sure where I am gonig wrong

Answer (score 1):

Since, items return the tuple of key,value you need to use index [1] in the lambda function.

```
>>> sortedByWinPct2 = {k:v for k, v in sorted(dict2.items(), key= lambda v:v[1][0]['plyoffStats'][0], reverse=True)}
>>> sortedByWinPct2
{'Pittsburgh Steelers': [{'plyoffStats': [19, 13, 790.0, 730.0, {'winPct': 0.594}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [5, 3]}, {'div': [8, 4]}, {'conf': [4, 4]}, {'sb': [2, 2]}]}], 'Seattle Seahawks': [{'plyoffStats': [14, 13, 659.0, 593.0, {'winPct': 0.519}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [7, 4]}, {'div': [3, 7]}, {'conf': [3, 0]}, {'sb': [1, 2]}]}], 'Jacksonville Jaguars': [{'plyoffStats': [7, 7, 337.0, 357.0, {'winPct': 0.5}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [4, 2]}, {'div': [3, 2]}, {'conf': [0, 3]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}], 'Houston Texans': [{'plyoffStats': [4, 6, 194.0, 253.0, {'winPct': 0.4}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [4, 2]}, {'div': [0, 4]}, {'conf': [0, 0]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}], 'Miami Dolphins': [{'plyoffStats': [3, 8, 126.0, 309.0, {'winPct': 0.273}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [3, 5]}, {'div': [0, 3]}, {'conf': [0, 0]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}], 'Buffalo Bills': [{'plyoffStats': [1, 6, 140.0, 170.0, {'winPct': 0.143}]}, {'round': [{'wc': [1, 5]}, {'div': [0, 1]}, {'conf': [0, 0]}, {'sb': [0, 0]}]}]}
>>>
```

Answer (score -2):

`v[0]` is the dictionary *key*. You need to access the dictionary *value*, then the first element of the value (which yields a dictionary), then the value of the plyoffStats key so:

```
sortedByWinPct2 = {k:v for k, v in sorted(dict2.items(), key= lambda v:v[1][0]['plyoffStats'], reverse=True)}
```

(no need to remind dictionaries are sorted from version 3.6, not before, that should work on any python >= 3.6)

Comment: This worked Jean. Dang thank you. I was so confused